# Cannot access certain directories in HTTP mode

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a site that I'm trying to run in HTTPS, except for certain directories.  The commands I have in .htaccess put the site automatically into HTTPS, but my /search and /search-results do not redirect over to HTTP.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^search$ http://www.example.com/search [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^search-results$ http://www.example.com/search-results [R=301,L]
```

Can someone please tell me the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(search|search-results)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(search|search-results)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```